# React-Redux - How to update the Id

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have the following state:

```
users: {
    'user-0': {
        id: 'user-0',
        title: 'Bob'
    },
    'user-1': {
        id: 'user-1',
        title: 'John'
    },
    ...
```

I would like to change user-1's id by user-12 for example:

```
users: {
    'user-0': {
        id: 'user-0',
        title: 'Bob'
    },
    'user-12': {
        id: 'user-12',
        title: 'John'
    },
    ...
```

What is the easiest way to do that with the reducer ?
I was thinking about copying the user-1 data to a new entry by changing the ids, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without mutating data:

```
let data = {
  users : {
    'user-0': {
        id: 'user-0',
        title: 'Bob'
    },
    'user-1': {
        id: 'user-1',
        title: 'John'
    },
    'user-2': {
        id: 'user-2',
        title: 'Bohn'
    }  
  }
}
  
let dataCopy = {
 ...data,
  'users' :{
    ...data.users,
    'user-12' : {
        ...data.users['user-1'],
        id: 'user-12'
    } 
  }
}
delete dataCopy.users['user-1'];
```

You need to make a deep copy of your object and only change that copy's properties. Do not mutate the original object. I am using `spread` operator and `delete`

Remember this is assuming your users follow the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

First Copy `user-1` data and add a new key `user-12` and set its value as `user-1`. then update the `id` property of `user-12` and remove `user-1` key from the state.

```js
users["user-12"] = {...users["user-1"], id:"user-12"};

// remove user-1 key from users state
delete users["user-1"]
```